# Azure release pipeline keeps adding ".scm" to the appservice's URL

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an appservice called compspiadev, and I am using Azure's Pipelines to set-up CI/CD. Created the build pipeline and build the project into an artifact to use it in the build pipeline. When I try to deploy I get the following error:

[image]

Now my appService doesn't have the ".scm." part in it, and in my configuration I don't set the name to have the KUDU endpoint it adds it automatically:

[image]

How can I fix this issue for it to deploy correctly?

Comment: Hi @Hussam Ahmed, Which agent are you using? Hosted agent or self-hosted agent? Could you please set the variable system.debug to true and then share the full log here? In addition, please notice the variable agent.WorkFolder value and ensure it points to self-hosted agent path.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT it is a hosted agent on a private DNS. I think this is happening because of the private DNS part. Can I use a build agent on a VM to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct. That is an network error which is because our Azure devops Hosted agent could not connect to the internal deployment endpoint of **ILB ASE**. *(As I mentioned in this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64109585/how-can-i-create-a-new-build-agent-on-azure-to-communicate-with-my-private-dns-a/64118277#64118277), I checked your app from our backend and found it is connecting to ILB ASE.)*

You can check this [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/azurermwebappdeployment.ts#L22) (*[actual working code snippet](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/deploymentProvider), I can not help you locate the exact code line since I don't know witch deploy method you used*), and you will found that the process of Azure app deployment via `Azure app service deploy` task is actually the process of communicate with app files to **Kudu service** (xxx.scm.azurewebsite.net).

*For example, if you are using **Run from package** type to deploy your web app, you can refer to this [code snippet](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/289e148c9ee3d1093a153139d121cb7b5eb3cf40/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/operations/KuduServiceUtility.ts#L190).*

After you configured ILB ASE, per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/using-an-ase#dns-configuration), the **scm** site is only available at `<appname>.scm.<asename>.appserviceenvironment.net`. But you should have known that **Hosted agent** is a dynamic-distribution Azure VM that is neither in nor connected to the virtual network.

That is why you encountered the error like could not connect to the remote computer `<appname>.scm.<asename>.appserviceenvironment.net`.

To resolve this issue, you need use private agent to execute your deployment pipeline. For how to configure a valid self agent so that it can communicate with your private DNS, you can follow this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64109585/how-can-i-create-a-new-build-agent-on-azure-to-communicate-with-my-private-dns-a/64118277#64118277) or this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mihansen/continuous-deployment-with-vststfs-and-app-service-environment-ase).

Answer (score 0):

As is visible in (the URL part of) the error message in your first image, you're deploying to an [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) (which is something of a special cookie).

> The Azure App Service Environment is an Azure App Service feature that provides a fully isolated and dedicated environment for securely running App Service apps at high scale.

As we can see in the second image, you don't have the checkbox "Deploy to Slot **or App Service Environment**" checked.

Check that checkbox, specify the Resource Group name, leave slot name set to production and you should be good to go.

> If the deployment target is an Azure App Service environment, leave the slot name as production and specify just the Resource Group name.

Source: [Azure App Service Deploy task - Prerequisites for the task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#prerequisites-for-the-task)

Comment: I added the changes that you recommended and still received the same error