# How can I create a new build agent on Azure to communicate with my private DNS and the release pipline on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a private DNS on an app-service, when I try to deploy to it, I am getting and error that it can't find the server to deploy to. I think that is because you can access it internally.

I wanted to see if I can create a build-agent on Azure that will be responsible for translating those Url to the specified app-service? I am not sure how I can go through that. Can someone give me some directions on what to do?

Comment: i have no experience with private DNS but if you are looking to build your own agent, you should probably start here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your previous question, I checked your app from our backend and found it is under **ILB ASE**.

By default, if you'd like to deploy web app manually from local machine (e.g. VisualStudio), you need make sure the machine can connect to the same virtual network.

Same as this, Azure devops is an internet-based CI systems, the CI/CD process will be successful with ILB ASE if the Build agent is **internet accessible** and **on the same network as ILB ASE**.  We have detailed explanation on this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase#publish-with-an-ilb-ase).

> Internet-based CI systems, such as GitHub and Azure DevOps, will still
> work with an ILB ASE if the build agent is internet accessible and on
> the same network as ILB ASE. So in case of Azure DevOps, if the build
> agent is created on the same VNET as ILB ASE (different subnet is
> fine), it will be able to pull code from Azure DevOps git and deploy
> to ILB ASE. If you don't want to create your own build agent, you need
> to use a CI system that uses a pull model, such as Dropbox.

---

**How to**:

You can follow this [official blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mihansen/continuous-deployment-with-vststfs-and-app-service-environment-ase) to deploy a build agent into the vNet where the ASE is deployed.

*Tips*:

We have released the Agent `v2.175.2` now, so pls replace the [VSTSAgentUrl](https://github.com/hansenms/iac/blob/master/ase-agent/DSC/ConfigureASEBuildAgent.ps1#L21) value to `https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.175.2/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.175.2.zip`.